# Simple C Program User Enters 5 Names of Friends

Tags: c

The parameters of the program are described as follows: Create a program that allows a user to enter up to five names of friends. Use a two dimensional array to store the friends’ names. After each name is entered, the user should have the option to enter another name or print out a report that shows each name entered thus far.

My issue has been that it will store a two word name as two separate names, and additionally print the menu option twice. I can't seem to figure this one out so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

## include

```
int main(void)

{
char  cName[5][21]= {0};
int x=0;
int  iPick;


printf("Enter the name of 5 people\n\n");


for(x=0;x<=5;x++){
printf("Enter name %d:", x+1);
scanf("%s", cName[x]);



printf("\n\nWould you like to add another name or view current names stored?\n");
printf("1)\tAdd another name\n");
printf("2)\tView names stored\n");
scanf("%d", &iPick);
switch(iPick){
case 1:
    break;
case 2:
    for(x=0;x<=5;x++){
    printf("\nName %d is %s\n",x+1, cName[x]);
        }
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

scanf() is pissy about white space. It tends to hold anything after the white space in buffers and place it into the next variable available.

This will cause the loop to run twice without your user input. Basically it finishes the loop the first time, and then it sees the stdin buffer has something in it, so the scanf automatically picks that up and uses it as the next variable, so the menu gets printed a second time...because the program thinks that you entered two different names instead of one name with white space in it.

Check out this function instead:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Since the buffer is still not empty, it even won't block and ask for input.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your first "for" loop:
     for(x=0; x<5; x++)

Comment: He originally had it that way, but someone with quite literally almost no reputation at all (not sure how he edited someone else's post) edited it so that it had the equals sign in there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all scanf with the `%s` formating parameter doesn't allow you to input a string. It's only used to input a word. If the input is two words or more separated with spaces they will will be considered as separeted inputs. however you can use the gets function to input a string:

```
printf("Enter name %d: ", x+1);
gets(cName[x]);
```

The second you should change the for condition to x<5 to stop the loop at the fifth name and not the sixth.

The last think, you shouldn't use the switch inside the for loop otherwise if the user choses to print out the names and the x value still under 5 the program will start over again until the x value reachs 5. So just check the the iPick value, if it's 2 break the loop and move the print loop out of the first.

```
// Inside the fitst loop
if (iPick == 2) break;

// Out of the first loop
for (x=0; x<5; x++){
   printf("\nName %d is %s\n",x+1, cName[x]);
}
```

For a full code check here http://pastebin.com/nnhYsRh7